# How Do I loop through two things at the same time Python and use it in django template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to loop through a list and return two things in my view and display it in my template. I'm scraping data and I'm trying to get the text and the href so I can use them in my template. I'm new to both django and python. first I tried to do this in my views.py:

```
 for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    text = link.text
    href = link.get

#links = soup.find_all("a")

ella = "ella"
context = {
    #"links": links,
    "ella": ella,
    "text": text,
    "href": href
```

and this in my template.html

```
{% for link in links %}
    {{ text }}
    {{ href }}
{% endfor %}
```

and I also tried this

```
{% for link in links %}
    {{ link.text }}
    {{ link.href }}
{% endfor %}
```

it didn't work and in my views I got the following error

```
local variable might be referenced before assignment
```

so I added global

```
 global text, href

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    text = link.text
    href = link.get

#links = soup.find_all("a")

ella = "ella"
context = {
    #"links": links,
    "ella": ella,
    "text": text,
    "href": href
}
```

but it still didn't work. What's the proper syntax to achieve the result I want. Any help or guidance is welcomed.

Comment: @surfer190 still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) in your code:

```
 links = []

 for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append((link.text, link.get))

context = {'links': links}
```

And then use them in the template as:

```
{% for text, href in links %}
    {{ text }}
    {{ href }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must define your view (it is a function) in `views.py` like this (`template.html` must be in `templates` directory):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    return render(request, 'template.html', dict(links=links))
```

And yours `urls.py` must contain binding for this view:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.myview, name='index'),
]
```

`render()` receives context dictionary as a third positional argument.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render